# Batch File get Specific IP into Variable

Tags: cmd, ip, netsh

I am trying to select a specific IP address in a windows batchfile. This line of code works, but gets the wrong IP address:

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /R /C:"IPv4 Address"') do (set newip=%%a)
```

If I type this at the command line, it gets a single line containing the IP address I'm looking for:

```
netsh interface IPv4 show addresses "Ethernet 2" | findstr /R /C:"IP Address"
```

However, when I try to embed that into the line from above to get the IP address into a variable, it throws the error "'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%a in ('netsh interface IPv4 show addresses "Ethernet 2" ^| findstr /R /C:"IP Address"') do (set newip=%%a)
```

Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong?

FYI, the reason why I'm trying to select this is that I have a program that sets an entry in my hosts file to point to my current IP, so that the site I'm running locally can use a specific domain. The problem with the existing code is that I have two IPv4 addresses - one from a VPN, and the other from my local router - and that code is selecting the wrong IP address.

Many thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] and share the rest of your batch file (the error re "else" is coming from somewhere else in the batch file).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more code containing both `if` and `else` statements. Note that using `if ... ( ... ) else ( ... )` next  _must_ be on the same line: `) else (`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your findstr parameters are wrong. You have specified use regular expression AND use literal. RegEx will win so you are searching for **IP** OR **Address**. Remove the `/r`.

Also your tokens/delims are wrong - you are getting a lot of spaces in your variable. This makes colon and space a delimiter.

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %a in ('netsh interface IPv4 show addresses "local area connection 7" ^| findstr /C:"IP Address"') do (set newip=%a)
```

How did I discover this. I unwound your command back to individual commands and ran each of those. Once I could see the output it was obvious.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance! The added delims and removing the /r did the trick! Also, what you said about figuring it out took a minute to click - I hadn't realized I could reduce the number of % on the variable and change the variable assignment to echo instead in order to see the output (it has been 8 years since I did any batch file programming, and even then it wasn't extensive), but now it makes sense - thanks so much for teaching me to fish and throwing in a salmon to feed me while I learn!